# SEDE tries to auto-login when I pick my OpenID provider but fails

Tags: support, data-explorer, login

When I try and login (today) on http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries and choose my open id provider (myopenid) it tries to auto log me in before I can even type my username (subdomain)... thus I get logged in as `John Doe 52` or something like that.

I get the feeling that the value in my local/session storage might have been wiped.. but the key is still there? (not sure how I can easily check in Firefox/Firebug).  If so, it seems like the code should be a bit more robust to ensure that the stored username or whatever is stored is `!= ""`.

I'm fairly sure this has worked in the past as I have created several queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you go to the logout page (on a SE 2.0 site, not sure if SEDE supports this) and click "Log Out Everywhere"?

[image]
<sub>(source: [stackoverflow.com](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/wp-content/uploads/log-out-everywhere-button.png))</sub>

That will clear HTML 5 Local Storage, and thus your network login.

Comment: hmm, tried that... logged out everywhere... re-logged in on Stackoverflow... then here... tried SEDE... no luck. tried to login on SEDE and I get the error "Message signature was incorrect" (after it tries to auto log me in... and if I manually type my open id url and click login.

Comment: @scun might be a bug in SEDE

Comment: hmm, ok, no worries... I'll give it a re-go tomorrow, thanks @Jeff.

Answer (score 0):

I've been having trouble too, very similar to yours.  Couldn't get past "Message signature was incorrect" when trying to use my regular provider (myOpenId).  Tried Google next which failed with a 404 on my assigned user ID page.  The next attempt worked.  I did end up with a different user name though.  Google's, not the one I get through the myOpenId login.  SEDE is, erm, different.

Comment: is login to data.se working now for you?

Comment: @waffles - sorta, I'm jon.doe60 there.  No idea how to reset it, it doesn't matter much afaict.  While I got your ear, how do I reset the saved query parameter default?  I'm getting the wrong user ID on every query, resetting cookies didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I also have an unusual problem when using OpenID.  I get my open id through my ISP.  But if I'm logged into my ISP through a different subaccount, I can't log into a new SE site, because it automatically picks the wrong OpenID.

So I have to log out at my ISP,  log into the subaccount I use with SE, log into SE, and log into the new (to me)  SE site.  I only have to do this once.  Once I've logged into a site,  I can access that site even when I'm logged into my ISP on the wrong subaccount.